# When to use ReaderWriterLockSlim and When to use ConcurrentBag?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

Is it the same if I used `ConcurrentBag` (to handle scenario of one writer & multiple readers) instead of using `ReaderWriterLockSlim` on a List<> ??

**UPDATE 1:**
The scenario is that there are multiple threads that can reach a static list and some may need to read others may need to write, what I want is:
1- Allow only one thread to add\edit\delete from the list while there are no other threads trying to adding\editing\deleting on it.
2- Allow many threads to read from it at the same time if there's no thread adding\editing\deleting.

Comment: They are two different beasts.  It depends what you're trying to do.

Comment: As I said that I want to apply "one writer & multiple readers" scenario

Comment: How do you intend to do that using `ConcurrentBag`?

Comment: That's what I'm asking to be clarified, does ConcurrentBag do this for me ? because I've been told it does.

Comment: A `ConcurrentBag` is an unordered thread-safe collection, the only thing it handles is itself. If you need to synchronize around something else then it won't help you. Where were you told it does that?

Comment: It does the same thing if I used LOCK with it right ? only one user at a time.

Comment: If you use `lock (x) { ... }` with a `ConcurrentBag` you are limiting it down to 1 thread, regardless of what that thread does (assuming that all threads use the lock as well). I think you should outline what you need to do, this sounds like an X/Y problem.

Comment: Please explain a bit more: what do you mean by static list? how are you planning to read from the list and what do you mean in writing to the list?

Comment: A concurrent bag does not support deleting and will not protect you from a race condition while editing an item.
Locking a list with a ReaderWriterLockSlim will allow safe deletion and will allow safe editing provided the editing is done within the write lock scope.

Comment: @YosefO thanks that is the answer I was waiting for, can you please add it as an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scenario it sounds like you should be using a ReaderWriterLockSlim on a list.

A concurrent bag does not support deleting (at all) and editing is not safe.
Locking a list with a ReaderWriterLockSlim will allow safe deletion and will allow safe editing provided the editing is done within the write lock scope.

Even though both constructs are related to synchronization and threading they are definitely not interchangeable.

- ConcurrentBag is a collection which you can add, take, peek and (most importantly) enumerate in a thread safe way.
- ReaderWriterLockSlim is a synch object which allows to read lock or write lock on whatever you want.

Comment: As I read that ReaderWriterLockSlim allow for one writer to enter only with no readers, and for multiple readers if there's no writer has the lock.
Does ConcurrentBag  apply this by it self ?

Comment: ConcurrentBag allows for safe reading and writing at the same time but not any kind of reading and writing. 

It allows only for Take and Add.

Comment: So it's more like using LOCK on List:
Lock(lstObject)

Comment: It's almost equivalent to a ReaderWriterLockSlim on an ICollection which has less features than a List.

Comment: If we assume there is a purpose behind actually implementing a `ConcurrentBag`, as opposed to just locking a list, then it's *like* it, but I would think a `ConcurrentBag` is more optimized for the job it does. I mean, if all it does is place a lock around a list, why did anyone prioritize writing that code into the framework as opposed to other stuff?

Comment: LasseV.Karlsen & Yosef please read the update, this is the scenario I want to apply.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Of course they are not the same in terms of implementation - ConcurrentBag is intended for a certain consumer/producer where many consumers and producers run concurrently. Using ReaderWriterLockSlim could perform better in few writers/many readers scenarios.

Comment: Yes, but the missing piece is the scenario that the OP has now edited in. Until that scenario, the question was comparing apples and oranges.